# How to use two various authentication in single Azure Function App?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have two http triggered functions in my Azure Function App project ,need to use `Function` and `Admin` level authentication for this.

I Know about below two key's and its uses.

`HostKey`  -- Use for Function App all the functions

`Function Key` --  Use for specific one function of Function App project

**Query :**

Host key of all the functions of Azure Function App will be same ?, because every functions has own `Function key` and `Host key` settings in portal.

but, we can use common host key for all the functions of azure function app ,then why maintaining host key individually in function integrate settings ?

Answer (score 1):

If you press the `Click to show` to display the value you will notice that all the host keys values are identical between functions under the same function app. so its just a weird (not even weird) ui decision they had to make